# I can't put some delay/animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to set a top in a div, for show the notices.
Now i just want to put a delay to this function (effect), because the "top" is set to fast, and it's so horrible.

```
var rolarbaixo = function() {     
var newtop = $('.plugin-noticias-rolar').position().top - 80;
$('.plugin-noticias-rolar').css('top', newtop + 'px').delay( 800 );
}
```

I tried to use .delay, but doesn't work.

Any help?

Comment: I'd use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` instead of `delay`

Comment: Do you want the change in position to be delayed, or do you want it animated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gues what you want here is [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to keep a smooth transition, try this:

```
var rolarbaixo = function() {     
  var newtop = $('.plugin-noticias-rolar').position().top - 80;
  $('.plugin-noticias-rolar').animate({top : newtop + 'px'},800);
}
```