# Count element clicks and define an max

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to count an element clicks, and, in the right number call some action.

```
var count = 0;
document.getElementById("rolarbaixo").onClick = function(e) {
     if( count >= 3 ) {
        var elem = document.getElementById("noticia");
            elem.setAttribute("style","top: 0px;");
     }
     else {
          count ++;
     }
};
```

When i clicked 3 times in the link "rolarbaixo" the div "noticia" set the "top: 0px;", but this doesn't work.
Why?

Answer (score 1):

It's `onclick` in lowercase

```
var count = 0;
document.getElementById("rolarbaixo").onclick = function (e) {
    if (count >= 2) {
        var elem = document.getElementById("noticia");
        elem.style.top = "0px";
    } else {
        count++;
    }
};
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/M9Xwa/3/)

And it's `>= 2` for three clicks (zero based and all).

AS the question is tagged jQuery, this would be it

```
$('#rolarbaixo').on('click', function() {
    var clicked = $(this).data('clicked') || 0;
    if (clicked >= 2) $('#noticia').css('top', 0);
    $(this).data('clicked', ++clicked);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/M9Xwa/4/)

Comment: Oh, tried this dude, but doesn't work. / My Style is class, the id us just for idetify, maybe is this?

Comment: @user2154508 - You have to include any javascript that accesses DOM elements after those elements are loaded. Did you include the script right before the `</body>` tag or use a DOM loaded handler etc.

Comment: My script is in the <head> tag

Comment: @user2154508 - And that's why it doesn't work, place it right before `</body>` after all the HTML.

Comment: Now it works, but, my other script with add top doesn't work now, is that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336773/i-cant-put-some-delay-animation/21336847?noredirect=1#21336847

Comment: @user2154508 - Try it like this, can be added anywhere -> http://jsfiddle.net/pZ89w/

Answer (score 1):

count ++ should be count++. If you press F12, you will be able to get to the developer tools and [debug the javascript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820).

Answer (score 0):

Misprint in `else` statement and change `onclick` to lowercase:

```
var count = 0;
document.getElementById("rolarbaixo").onclick = function(e) {
     if( count >= 3 ) {
        var elem = document.getElementById("noticia");
            elem.setAttribute("style","top: 0px;");
     } else {
          count++;
     }
};
```